# Combining Two Sets of Information into A Header Title Using Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, cells, sections

I have a simple application with a Table View which has a plus button; the user clicks that and gets taken to a Modal View where they can enter the Date, Name, Amount and Title. When they click save, the VC dismisses and the information gets saved to the database; the table view then updates to display that information.

So the user adds Name, Title, Date and Amount into a view controller and that gets translated to the table view as:

- CelltextLabel = Name and Title
- DetailTextLabel = Amount
- Section Header = Date

So there's always 4 sets of information, but this looks a bit messy. I am using Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController. I have searched and cannot find too many references to this but is it possible to have the DATE and TITLE be the section header rather than just the Date?

If so, any help on this would be appreciated.

My code is as follows for the key components that make up the Section Headers:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"occasion.dateOfEvent" cacheName:nil];

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id  sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
}
```

With the CellforRowAtIndex being:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", info.name, info.title];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = info.amount;
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add a property to your managed object subclass like:

```
- (NSString *)dateAndTitle {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.date, self.title];
}
```

and initialize your `NSFetchedResultsController` using `dataAndTitle` for `sectionNameKeyPath` like:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"occasion. dateAndTitle" cacheName:nil];
```

Make sure your fetch request is sorted by date and title or you'll see duplicate sections.